# when to use reach

Tags: past-tense, questions

I have a question about the usage of the word 'reach' in the past tense.

Which one is the correct question to ask my friend to make sure he reached there before me, while I was still travelling towards that direction?

> "Did you already reach at the clinic?"

or

> "When did you reach the clinic?"

Comment: If the clinic is your friend's final destination, then I would use "arrive at", unless the focus is specifically on the distance.

Answer (score 2):

The second is fine. The first is not: try "Have you already reached the clinic". what is wrong with the first is, that being in the simple past tense, it is worded as a question about an event in the past that has been concluded. So, it would be a good question to ask if you wanted to know whether your friend managed to get as far as the clinic last week. But in this case you are asking about an event that might or might not have happened at an unspecified time in the past, so the present perfect is the tense to use.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.